# What is the difference between --query and --filter in aws cli? Which is suggested to be used?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am starting to pick up aws cli and I just wanted to know the difference between `--query` and `--filter` in aws cli? When we should use `--query` and `--filter` options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially `--filter` is the **condition** used to select *which resources* you want described, listed, etc.

On the other hand `--query` is the **list of fields** that you want returned in the response. You can do some simple filtering with `--query` as well but `--filter` tends to be more powerful.

Example from `aws ec2 describe-volumes help`:

> **To describe tagged volumes and filter the output**
>
> This  example  command describes all volumes that have the tag key **Name**
>   and a value that begins with **Test**. The output is  filtered  to  display
>   only the **tags and IDs** of the volumes.
>
> Command:
>
> ```
> aws ec2 describe-volumes \
>     --filters Name=tag-key,Values="Name" Name=tag-value,Values="Test*" \
>     --query 'Volumes[*].{ID:VolumeId,Tag:Tags}'
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> [
>   {
>      "Tag": [ { "Value": "Test2", "Key": "Name" } ],
>      "ID": "vol-1234567890abcdef0"
>   },
>   {
>      "Tag": [ { "Value": "Test1", "Key": "Name" } ],
>      "ID": "vol-049df61146c4d7901"
>   }
> ]
> ```

As you can see the `--filter` is used to select the required records (i.e. those with tag **Name** starting with string **Test***. And `--query` is then used to only retrieve the **Tags** (as *Tag*) and the **VolumeId** (as *ID*).

Hope that helps :)

Comment: this isn't correct. You can imitate that exact filter with:  `--query 'Volumes[?Tag[?Key==\`Name\` && starts_with(Value, \`Test\`)]][].{ID:VolumeId,Tag:Tags}'`