# AWS-CLI - Find ELB by Name tag

Tags: aws-cli

I'm trying to find a load balancer that has a `Name` tag with some value.

```
aws elb describe-load-balancers --query 'LoadBalancerDescriptions[*].LoadBalancerName'
```

I'm iterating over the results and running:

```
aws elb describe-tags \
--load-balancer-names some-load-balancer \
--query 'TagDescriptions[?Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value == `my-desired-name-value`]'
```

The result is always empty even though this:

```
aws elb describe-tags \
--load-balancer-names some-load-balancer \
--query 'TagDescriptions[].Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value'
```

Does return `my-desired-name-value`.
I'd like to get the entire object of the tags, using only JMESPath, I can't use `jq` here.

Desired output:

```
{
    "TagDescriptions": [
        {
            "LoadBalancerName": "some-load-balancer",
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Key": "SomeTag",
                    "Value": "SomeValue"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "Name",
                    "Value": "my-desired-name-value"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

What's wrong with my [JMESPath](https://jmespath.org/) query?

Answer (score 6):

You're trying to use `--query` to perform the role of `--filter` and unfortunately `describe-tags` does not support the `--filter` option.

The `--query` option allows you to select what fields are returned in the response.  When available `--filter` allows you select which resources you want returned.  It's described in more detail [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/941250/what-is-the-difference-between-query-and-filter-in-aws-cli-which-is-suggest)

You can use `jq` to perform the function of the filter.  I highly recommend it because AWS does not implement the `--filter` option for all CLI commands.

For your example try something like:

```
aws elb describe-tags --load-balancer-names some-load-balancer \
| jq -r '.TagDescriptions[] |select (.Tags[].Value=="my-desired-name-value")'
```

A bit more complex is to filter on the Tag Key and Value:

```
aws elb describe-tags --load-balancer-names some-load-balancer \
| jq -r '.TagDescriptions[] | . as $i \
| (select ($i.Tags[].Value=="my-desired-name-value")) and (select ($i.Tags[].Key=="Name")) \
| $i'
```

#### Output

```
{
  "LoadBalancerName": "some-load-balancer",
  "Tags": [
    {
      "Key": "Type",
      "Value": "classic"
    },
    {
      "Key": "Name",
      "Value": "my-desired-name-value"
    }
  ]
}
```

#### References

- [JQ Docs](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

Comment: I should've said, cannot use `jq`. I must accomplish this using `--query`.

Comment: Edit your question with the desired output and any other requirements you might have and I'll play with it.

Comment: Added description thanks!

Comment: In case you're using the `aws elbv2` command, note that `aws elbv2 describe-tags` sub-command only accepts ARNs with the `--resource-arns` flag.

Answer (score -2):

aws elbv2 describe-tags --resource-arns  | jq -r '.TagDescriptions[] | . as $i | (select($i.Tags[].Value | test(".*-.*-05-myteam.*-.*"))) and (select ($i.Tags[].Key=="Name")) | $i.ResourceArn'

Comment: You can use the regular expression to filter the Name tag as above using test(regex)

Comment: [Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer). Furthermore, asker already said they can't use `jq`.